# How to change default tag delimiters in mustache sharp

Tags: c#, mustache, texttemplate

I use mustache sharp and according to the mustache 5 [documentation](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) we can change the  default tag delimiters.

```
   * {{default_tags}}
{{=<% %>=}}
* <% erb_style_tags %>
<%={{ }}=%>
* {{ default_tags_again }}
```

should we change the default tag in html template? I use the same syntax in my template but it does not work as mentioned in documentation and above.
my template is

```
       <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
{{#newline}}
        <list-breadcrumb object="{{DisplayName}}"></list-breadcrumb>
{{#newline}}
{{=<% %>=}}
        <h1 class="h1"><%DisplayName%></h1>
<%={{ }}=%>
{{#newline}}
    </div>
```

after i compile and render the template, the {{DisplayName}} replace with my model.DisplayName but the <%DisplayName%> does not replace and come to the output like <%DisplayName%>.

Thanks